# Transferring tty1 to systemd on Ubuntu Server 16.10

Tags: 14.04, server, chromium, tty

On Ubuntu Server 14.04 I was using tty1.conf to launch a chromium browser window to display a web page. Which was simple enough. However, on Ubuntu 16.10 tty1.conf is gone and I don't have a good understanding of systemd. This is the code on tty1.conf

```
# tty1 - getty
#
# This service maintains a getty on tty1 from the point the system is
# started until it is shut down again.

start on stopped rc RUNLEVEL=[2345] and (
            not-container or
            container CONTAINER=lxc or
            container CONTAINER=lxc-libvirt)

stop on runlevel [!2345]

respawn
#exec /sbin/getty -8 38400 tty1
exec /usr/bin/startx /home/username/launch.sh
```

And this on launch.sh

```
#!/bin/sh
xrandr -o right
sleep 1; xset s off
sleep 1; xset -dpms
rm -r /home/username/chrome-home
chromium-browser --kiosk http://localhost:81 --user-data-dir=/home/username/chrome-home
```

This code is used to run launch.sh using tty1 and launch.sh was used to display the content on a localhost webpage. Can you please help me to recreate this using systemd. Many thanks!

Comment: What are you trying to do run a kiosk ? systemd is probably not the best method to do this, see http://www.instructables.com/id/Setting-Up-Ubuntu-as-a-Kiosk-Web-Appliance/?ALLSTEPS . If you are running a kiosk, and have to ask, you are probably better off running a kiosk distro.

Comment: See also https://tuxdiary.com/2014/11/05/linux-distros-for-kiosks/